# How to explain a multilevel model bias towards one of the levels?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, bias

My multilevel model's 2 levels consist of land surface images and meteorological readings from different places. The readings are level 2, with 7 variables and 1 observation per group. The images are level 1, with 5 variables (different images) where each *pixel* is an observation. The images are of size 1000 x 1000, which means that per group, there are 1 *million* observations.

[image]

The predictand (left) is taken by a thermal camera, while the predictor images are all taken by a more accurate normal camera, and some of them show these features (like trees) vividly.
The results of the model (on the right) after cross validation are wildly inaccurate numerically, but perfectly capture every spatial detail in the image, clearly having a massive bias toward the first level.

My question is 2-fold:

1. How do I show the model's bias towards one level?
2. How many observations is, in fact, too many? Should I cut the images down in size?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the data hierarchy and the model you are estimating? I see 1 million pixels, 5 images, and readings. I'm not sure how all that fits together.

Comment: @ErikRuzek The predictand is the surface temperature from an image, which has one million pixels, such that every pixel is an observation. There are 5 image predictors (same scale), and 7 more predictors which are readings from a meteorological station on site (every reading is an observation). This is why we chose a multilevel model. Does this clarify things?

Comment: So the outcome is a temperature reading from the thermal image? And each image has 1 million thermal readings?

Comment: Yes. So that for testing, I would input 5 images, and get an image output.

Comment: What software are you using to fit this model ?

Comment: R at the moment

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about the data and the model. Can you show us your `lme4` code (or whatever you are using for the analysis)?

Comment: I did not. I build a model manually as I couldn't find a function that does quite what I needed. I got advice form a professor who said I can model the level with more observations first, then for the 2nd level use the coefficients from the first level as predictands. So that's what I built. In `lme4` the code, as I understand it, would be just a simple linear formula, with all the variables together, such that if I have 10 samples, there would be 10 million observations, where the image variables have unique observations, but the station variables have 1m identical observations per sample.